# Multiple transform function on Tailwind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

I would like to apply several tranform functions to **Tailwind CSS** for one element order from left to right like this :

```
transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(50%);
```

But if I apply class like this, rotation is applied last.

```
class="transform rotate-45 translate-x-1/2"
```

A link to illustrate my problem :
[Play.tailwindcss.com/R6PBP2OHPy](https://play.tailwindcss.com/R6PBP2OHPy)

Comment: can you attach the tailwind config file?

Comment: I have the default config file. I edit my question with a playground to illustrate my problem. @ElsaKarami

Comment: Set the origin to origin-left, this will allow you to rotate on the left center of the original space of the item
here is the edited illistration of what you posted

https://play.tailwindcss.com/r8gEZAZyAx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by rotating the parent div element and translating the child element. Not the most elegant solution but it works.

```
<div class="rotate-45">
  <img class="translate-x-12"/>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/dvZnRRaKq1